# JSLint line break format

Tags: javascript, jslint

I really can't understand how JSLint would like me to format this script:

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    window.isMobileDevice = function () {
        return (window.orientation !== undefined) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("IEMobile") !== -1);
    };
}());
```

I get this error:

```
Line is longer than 80 characters.
        return (window.orientation !== undefined) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("IEMobile") !== -1);
```

If I add a line break:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    window.isMobileDevice = function () {
        return (window.orientation !== undefined) ||
            (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("IEMobile") !== -1);
    };
}());
```

I get this error:

```
Expected '(' at column 8, not column 12.
            (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("IEMobile") !== -1);
```

How should the line break be formatted?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like it told you: `Expected '(' at column 8, not column 12.`. ;^D

Move that line back four spaces and you're golden.

This lints for me on [JSLint.com](http://jslint.com):

```
/*jslint browser*/
(function () {
    "use strict";

    window.isMobileDevice = function () {
        return (window.orientation !== undefined) ||
        (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("IEMobile") !== -1);
    };
}());
```

Note that I also had to remove the parameter `$` as it wasn't used.

#### But you can override that...

I think this is where I remark that JSLint is *very* opinionated, but luckily this is one place we can change it to work like you want. If you set [the "`white`space mess" directive](http://jslint.com/help.html#white), your code (minus the `$`) is fine as is.

```
/*jslint browser, white*/
(function () {
    "use strict";

    window.isMobileDevice = function () {
        return (window.orientation !== undefined) ||
            (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("IEMobile") !== -1);
    };
}());
```